# What was the volume of the Rocketdyne F-1 engine's main combustion chamber?

Tags: apollo-program, engines, engine-design, saturn-v

In the specifications of the F-1 available online, I can find its dimensions, weight, thrust, etc. but I couldn't find what was the volume of its main combustion chamber. Is this information available?

Comment: Can you infer/calculate its volume with the available dimensions?

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 No... the dimension of the engine include the nozzle and the plumbing, I didn't find the dimensions of just the combustion chamber anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using some very basic values we can get a crude approximation. With a diameter of $3.7\ m$ and an expansion ratio of $16$ we can infer that the throat area is around $\frac{\frac{\pi}{4}*3.7^2}{16}\approx 0.672\ m^2$. The characteristic length, $L^*$, of an engine is defined as follows:

$ L^* = \frac{V_c}{A_t}$
with $V_c$ the chamber volume and $A_t$ the throat area.

[Humble (p. 220)](https://nl1lib.org/book/16359089/7854de) gives the characteristic length of an oxygen/RP-1 engine to be between 1.02 - 1.27. Thus, a crude approximation of the chamber volume of the F-1 Engine becomes $.685$ - $.853\ m^3$

Answer (score 2):

The Rocketdyne F1 engine had a round disk injector. I found this archive of photos. The page with pictures of the F1 injector states it was 44 inches across.
link [here](http://heroicrelics.org/f-1-disassembly/injector/index.html): http://heroicrelics.org/f-1-disassembly/injector/index.html

Due to instability of combustion the original flat injector had to be modified with the addition of baffles. These worked well. So I found 2 pictures of an F1 from the bottom of the nozzle. It appears that the injector, combustion chamber and throat are all the same diameter and that the height of the chamber is less than 22 in. perhaps only 14 inches.

picture 1 from NASA page talking about the F1 unstable combustion [here](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/marshall/history/solving-combustion-instability-and-saving-americas-first-trips-to-the-moon.html)

picture 2 from Wikimedia.org [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/Saturn_V_Rocket_Booster.jpg)

Click on the pictures to enlarge or download.

Comment: In the second picture, the lower-right engine's appearance is misleading -- the injector appears the same size as the throat because it's further from the camera. The view angle into the lower-left engine makes it clear that the throat actually narrows, and the chamber is deeper than 22 inches.

Comment: The throat-to-exit area ratio is 16:1, making the throat diameter about 36".

Comment: Potentially good info, but an answer must give the volume.

Comment: Good deductions guys. The 36" looks correct.

Comment: I found an article on researchgate dot net, that says the L* = 1.22 m (which is 48.0 inches). Using throat area of .672 m², volume = .672 * 1.22 = .820 m³. Title of the paper is "Characteristic Lengths of Liquid Propellant Rocket Engines and the Influence of Chemical Reactions", from a mechanical engineering conference in Brazil in 2021. A number of engines listed.